# spark: SAXParseException while writing to parquet on s3

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read in some json, infer a schema, and write it out again as parquet to s3 (s3a). For some reason, about a third of the way through the writing portion of the run, spark always errors out with the error included below. I can't find any obvious reasons for the issue: it isn't out of memory; there are no long GC pauses. There don't seem to be any additional error messages in the logs of the individual executors.

The script runs fine on another set of data that I have, which is of a very similar structure, but several orders of magnitude smaller.

I am running spark 2.0.1-hadoop-2.7 and am using the FileOutputCommitter. The algorithm version doesn't seem to matter.

Edit:
This does not appear to be a problem in badly formed json or corrupted files. I have unzipped and read in each file individually with no error.

Here's a simplified version of the script:

```
object Foo {

  def parseJson(json: String): Option[Map[String, Any]] = {
    if (json == null)
      Some(Map())
    else
      parseOpt(json).map((j: JValue) => j.values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])
      }
  }
}

// read in as text and parse json using json4s
val jsonRDD: RDD[String] = sc.textFile(inputPath)
    .map(row -> Foo.parseJson(row))

// infer a schema that will encapsulate the most rows in a sample of size sampleRowNum
val schema: StructType = Infer.getMostCommonSchema(sc, jsonRDD, sampleRowNum)

// get documents compatibility with schema
val jsonWithCompatibilityRDD: RDD[(String, Boolean)] = jsonRDD
  .map(js => (js, Infer.getSchemaCompatibility(schema, Infer.inferSchema(js)).toBoolean))
  .repartition(partitions)

val jsonCompatibleRDD: RDD[String] = jsonWithCompatibilityRDD
  .filter { case (js: String, compatible: Boolean) => compatible }
  .map { case (js: String, _: Boolean) => js }

// create a dataframe from documents with compatible schema
val dataFrame: DataFrame = spark.read.schema(schema).json(jsonCompatibleRDD)
```

It completes the earlier schema inferring steps successfully. The error itself occurs on the last line, but I suppose that could encompass at least the immediately preceding statemnt, if not earlier:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to commit task
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DefaultWriterContainer$$commitTask$1(WriterContainer.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:258)
    ... 8 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:147)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:113)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:112)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetFileFormat.scala:569)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DefaultWriterContainer$$abortTask$1(WriterContainer.scala:282)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$2.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1354)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:399)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3480)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.deleteUnnecessaryFakeDirectories(S3AFileSystem.java:1147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.finishedWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AOutputStream.close(S3AOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.end(ParquetFileWriter.java:400)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:117)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetFileFormat.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DefaultWriterContainer$$commitTask$1(WriterContainer.scala:267)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:150)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListBucketObjectsResponse(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:279)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:75)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:141)
    ... 35 more
```

Here's my conf:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxPermSize=1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
spark.executor.memory   16G
spark.executor.uri  https://s3.amazonaws.com/foo/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.buffer.dir  /raid0/spark
spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.buffer.dir  /raid0/spark
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.timeout 500000
spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.multipart.uploads.enabled   true
spark.hadoop.parquet.block.size 2147483648
spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata    false
spark.jars.packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.0.1
spark.local.dir /raid0/spark
spark.mesos.coarse  false
spark.mesos.constraints  priority:1
spark.network.timeout   600
spark.rpc.message.maxSize    500
spark.speculation   false
spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema   false
spark.sql.planner.externalSort  true
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.task.cpus 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think for three possible reasons for this problem.

1. JVM version. AWS SDK checks for the following ones. "1.6.0_06",
   "1.6.0_13", "1.6.0_17", "1.6.0_65", "1.7.0_45". If you are using one
   of them, try upgrading.
2. Old AWS SDK. Refer to
   https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/460 for a workaround.
3. If you lots of files in the directory where you are writing these files, you might be hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13164. Consider increasing the timeout to larger values.

Answer (score 1):

A `SAXParseException` may indicate a badly formatted XML file.  Since the job fails roughly a third of the way through consistently, this means it's probably failing in the same place every time (a file whose partition is roughly a third of the way through the partition list).

Can you paste your script?  It may be possible to wrap the Spark step in a try/catch loop that will print out the file if this error occurs, which will let you easily zoom in on the problem.

Comment: Added the snippet. Maybe the place to add a try catch is in the `Foo.parseJson` method?

Answer (score 1):

From the logs:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

and

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler

It looks like you have a corrupted/incorrectly formatted file, and your error is actually occurring during the read portion of the task. You could confirm this by trying another operation that will force the read such as `count()`.

If confirmed, the goal would then be to find the corrupted file. You could do this by listing the s3 files, `sc.parallelize()` that list, and then trying to read the files in a custom function using `map()`.

```
import boto3
from pyspark.sql import Row    

def scanKeys(startKey, endKey):
    bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('bucketName')
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prefix', Marker=startKey):
        if obj.key < endKey:
            yield obj.key
        else:
            return

def testFile(s3Path):
    s3obj = boto3.resource('s3').Object(bucket_name='bucketName', key=key)
    body = s3obj.get()['Body']
    ...
    logic to test file format, or use a try/except and attempt to parse it
    ...
    if fileFormatedCorrectly == True:
        return Row(status='Good', key = s3Path)
    else:
        return Row(status='Fail', key = s3Path)


keys = list(scanKeys(startKey, endKey))
keyListRdd = sc.parallelize(keys, 1000)
keyListRdd.map(testFile).filter(lambda x: x.asDict.get('status') == 'Fail').collect()
```

This will return the s3 paths for the incorrectly formatted files

Comment: If the s3 path is `bucket_name/a/b/c/d.txt`, you'd want `bucket = 'bucket_name'` and `key = 'a/b/c/d.txt'`

Comment: Also, can you edit the comment to take out my bucket's name, please?

Comment: And I see you're using scala spark. This link might help with getting all the s3 objects https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pjrt/f1cad93b154ac8958e65/raw/7b0b764408f145f51477dc05ef1a99e8448bce6d/S3Puller.scala which was from http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219

Comment: What do you suggest for the logic to test the file format? These are large zipped files with linear json. Try and load each line as json and set the flag to false if there is an error?

Comment: Once you're to this point, you're reading in native Scala. I'd defer to you on the best way to read the file, but you have 2 choices. You could `map` the s3 keys attempt to parse the file, and return the contents of the entire file (or a fail status if there is an error). Or as you suggest, you could `flatMap`, and try to load each line, returning either a line or a status fail flag. Either way works and would depend on if you'd want some data from corrupted files (if you could get it)

Comment: So I tried doing all this in pyspark, loading each file and reading each line in as json, and there were no errors. So it doesn't appear to be a corrupted file.

Answer (score 0):

**For Googlers:**

If you:

- have a versioned bucket
- use `s3a://`
- see `ListBucketHandler` and `listObjects` in your error message

Quick solution:

- use `s3://` instead of `s3a://`, which will use S3 driver provided by EMR

You may see this error because `s3a://` in older versions uses `S3::ListObjects` (v1) API instead of `S3::ListObjectsV2`. The former would return extra info like owner, and is not robust against large number of deletion markers. Newer versions of the `s3a://` driver solved this problem, but you could always use the `s3://` driver instead.

[Quote](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13811):

> - the V1 list API experience always returns 5000 entries (as set in fs.s3a.paging.maximum
> - except for the final entry
> - if you have versioning turned on in your bucket, deleted entries retain tombstone markers with references to their versions
> - which will surface in the S3-side of list calls, but get stripped out from the response
> - so...for a very large tree, you may end up S3 having to keep a channel open while is skips of thousands to millions of deleted
>   objects before it can find actual ones to return.
> - which can time out connections.

[Quote](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/aws-sdk-for-java-1-10-75/):

> Introducing a new version of the ListObjects (ListObjectsV2) API that allows listing objects with a large number of delete markers.

[Quote](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-unresponsive-list/):

> If there are thousands of delete markers, the list operation might timeout。